# how to load sapbex.xla when the workbook opens

Tags: excel, vba, sap-bw, xla

I open a query from SAP BW... I make all the changes I need and I even check the box that says Refresh query every time you open the workbook. The problem is that when I reopen the workbook it's just like a regular Excel, because the `SAPBEX.xla` file is not loaded anymore.

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

I want the workbook updated with the latest data every time I open the workbook.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar to SAP BW. Do you automatically query with Excel connections? What is SAPBEX.vba?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake... it's sapbex.xla ... an ad-in for connecting and refreshing the queries

Comment: so the connection to SAP BW is operated by this add-in? Is it public? Apart from the fact that the add-in shouldn't get unloaded, I don't think I can help you here.

Comment: I solved the problem in the end... I had to set it up from Excel but now the add-in loads no matter what excel file I open... is there a way to make it load only when I open a specified file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an application event (see [Chip Pearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx)).

Put this code in the `This Workbook` module of your `PERSONAL.XLSM` (see [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/personal.htm)).

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

And in a module:

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "New Workbook: " & Wb.Name
    'or better check here if this is your workbook and activate the addin
End Sub
```